# Object not visible inside function of Chrome content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, closures, self-invoking-function

I'm developing a simple Chrome extension. Inside a content script (called `script.js`) I have the following code:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    const buttonText = {
        enabled: "enabled",
        disabled: "disabled"
    }

    function inject() {
        if (window.location.search.includes(`&lc=`)) {
            var initialButtonText = buttonText.disabled //<-- POSSIBLE ERROR
        } else {
            var initialButtonText = buttonText.enabled //<-- POSSIBLE ERROR
        }

        //Do some more stuff...
    }

    document.addEventListener(`spfdone`, inject)
    inject();
})()
```

Usually, this code works as expected. Occasionally, though, it throws an error at one of the two lines indicated above in `script.js`, stating `buttonText` is not defined. I have been able to catch it in the debugger a few times right before it threw this error. In those instances, `buttonText` was defined in the top level function but not visible inside `inject`. I don't know of anything which changed between successful runs and error producing runs. Is there a well known JavaScript or Chrome related reason this would be happening? Or must it be a problem I'm creating in my code?

Here's the extension's manifest in case its relevant:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Title",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.youtube.com/*"
            ],
            "css": [
                "styles.css"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.youtube.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "script.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Please describe in more detail the circumstances under which it fails so we can duplicate the problem.

Comment: @Makyen I have added some more code to the question. It now shows the complete contents of script.js at the time of the last crash (not including code that had been commented out by that point). I do not know exactly how to recreate the bug because, as I said, it only happens occasionally and with no change in the code.

Comment: @Makyen Also, sorry about the original title. I forgot to change it from my last search terms.

Comment: What do you mean by *crashes*? What happens exactly?

Comment: @rsanchez I've updated the question again. I just meant that it stopped script execution at those points with a `buttonText not defined` error